# How to add a ; after a given instance using Python 3

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

So, I have a txt file that has the below content in it:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `table1`(
  `tab_id bigint COMMENT 'The unique identifier of thetable')
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  *
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
* 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  *
LOCATION
  *
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1556u3ehw27')
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `aud2`(
  `application_id` bigint COMMENT 'Unique Id that represents each application created')
COMMENT 'contains application level details. every application will have one entry'
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  *
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
* 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  *
LOCATION
  *
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1trh7')
```

I am trying to write a program that inserts a ; specifically after the last parentheses after tblproperties. So the output should be like:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `table1`(
  `tab_id bigint COMMENT 'The unique identifier of thetable')
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  *
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
* 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  *
LOCATION
  *
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1556u3ehw27');
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `audit_application`(
  `application_id` bigint COMMENT 'Unique Id that represents each application created')
COMMENT 'contains application level details. every application will have one entry'
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  *
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
* 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  *
LOCATION
  *
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1trh7');
```

Here is my stating code but doesn't run but it deletes everything after the last ) which isn't what I want:

```
f = open("/home/files", 'rt', encoding='latin-1')
source=f.read()

with open("/home/files/sampl8.sql","w") as output:
    output.write(source[:source.find(')')+1].replace('"', ''))
```

Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re.sub` to find and replace all instances of `TBLPROPERTIES()` with `TBLPROPERTIES();`:

```
import re

f = open("/home/files", 'rt', encoding='latin-1')
source=f.read()

with open("/home/files/sampl8.sql","w") as output:
    output.write(re.sub(r'(TBLPROPERTIES \(.*?\))', r'\1;', f, flags=re.DOTALL))
```

Comment: it gives me an error of encoding is an invalid keyword arguemnt for this function. Do you know why that is?

Comment: Is the error throwing on the file open line? What's the full error? you might also try to remove the `encoding` argument on line 3 since you're probably not receiving things with a latin encoding

Answer (score 0):

You can just find the exact strings using regex and replace it like below. Using `set` just to make sure we are not replacing duplicates.

```
import re

t = '''
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `table1`(
  `tab_id bigint COMMENT 'The unique identifier of thetable')
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  *
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
* 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  *
LOCATION
  *
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1556u3ehw27')
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `aud2`(
  `application_id` bigint COMMENT 'Unique Id that represents each application created')
COMMENT 'contains application level details. every application will have one entry'
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  *
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
* 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  *
LOCATION
  *
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1trh7')
'''

for i in set(re.findall(r'TBLPROPERTIES \(.*?\)', t, flags=re.DOTALL)):
    t = t.replace(i, i + ';')

print(t)
```